# Laravel get one value from eager load

Tags: php, laravel

I've got this query in Laravel that's returning all forums with some extra information:

```
return Forum::with(['messages.user' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}])->withCount('messages')->paginate(10);
```

but now it eager loads all related messages as well but I only need the author from a message. How could I get this result?

Comment: I think you cannot use eager loading for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table you have for your `Message` model is `messages` and that it has the columns `forum_id` and `user_id`, and the table for your `User` model is `users` you could just define a `belongsToMany` and get the information that way:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'messages')->distinct();
}
```

then:

```
return Forum::with(['users' => function($query){
     $query->select('users.id', 'users.name');
}])->withCount('messages')->paginate(10);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without eager loading,

//for a particular forum

//Get a forum entity

```
$forum = Forum::find($id);
```

// Get its messages as a Collection

```
$forumMessages = $forum->messages;
```

// Iterate over each message on the Collection to find its author. This will look for id in the User model based on the 'author_id' stored by you in the message table.The collection $forumMessages will now have the author's name. This is just to give you an idea. Structure accordingly to your needs.

```
 $forumMessages->each(function ($message){
  $message->author = User::find($message->author_id)->name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
return Forum::with([
    'messages' => function ($messages) {
        return $messages->with([
            'user' => function ($user) {
                return $user->select('id', 'name');
            }
        ])->select('id', 'author'); // you get author from messages
    }
])->withCount('messages')->paginate(10);
```

This also eager loads but you only get `id` and `author`. `id` is needed to make the relationship with user.

Comment: This looks the best solution. But it throws an error: ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `name` from `message` where `message`.`forum_id` in (1, 2))```

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to get `name` field from `massage` table. Check if you have such field there.

Comment: Yes it's because of the last ```->select('id', 'author');``` when I remove that it works but it loads all messages aswel. That's what I'm trying to prevent.